# Can you use the whereIn condition twice in a compound query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to use `whereIn`twice in the one query in firestore?  something..like this

```
query.where('venue.id', whereIn: ['11','22','33',]).where('order',whereIn: ['Pending','Preparing']),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, according to the docs:

> You can use only one in or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't use both `in` and `array-contains-any` in the same query.

Also if you have two `whereIn`, it should throw the following error:

```
      if (operator == 'in') {
        assert(!hasIn, "You cannot use 'in' filters more than once."); //this error
        hasIn = true;
      }
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L421